# Blazor InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager[...]

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I know that that error was mentioned a few times on StackOverflow, unfortunately, the solutions mentioned before doesn't work.

I have such an error that comes from _LoginPartial.cshtml. My application is based on the standard Blazor server template (authorisation with user accounts). Such an exception is on the login and registration pages.

```
InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' has been registered.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPagePropertyActivator+<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<CreateActivateInfo>b__1(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.PropertyActivator<TContext>.Activate(object instance, TContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPagePropertyActivator.Activate(object page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPageActivator.Activate(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialCoreAsync(string partialViewName, object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData, TextWriter writer)
AspNetCore.Pages_Shared__Layout.<ExecuteAsync>b__21_1() in _Layout.cshtml
+
                        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_LoginPartial");
```

I think that problem is at one of those files AspNetUser.cs, _LoginPartial.cshtml or Startup.cs (probably that file) Unfortunately I don't know where.

```
//AspNetUser.cs
public class AspNetUser : IdentityUser
{
public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
//_LoginPartial.cshtml

@using MyApp.Data
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<AspNetUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<AspNetUser> UserManager

//Startup.cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddIdentity<AspNetUsers, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddDefaultUI();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
            services.AddSingleton<DonationRequestService>();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error means that your service config is expecting `IdentityUser` as the type used by the UserManager.

1. Your service config builds Identity for `AspNetUsers` - not AspNetUser which you're expecting and not IdentityUser which the app is expecting
2. Your service config adds a Scoped service which uses IdentityUser, but appears that it should use `AspNetUser` which is what you're trying to use in your UserManager (and also inherits from IdentityUser anyway)
3. No service config is set up for IdentityUser which isn't a problem, as long as the rest of your code isn't expecting IdentityUser specifically, so check that it's not used anywhere.